# How to properly un-nest and flatten an array of javascript objects with an array inside them (X-amount of times)

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, javascript-objects

I'm currently working with an array of javascript objects with X-amount of array's with the same type of object inside it, in a specific property (in this case, 'modelChildren')

I would like to flatten this into just one array of objects, and return the level at which it was found. The solution does not have to be plain javascript, as I use lodash for many situations. Ideally I would also like to remove the 'modelChildren' field once finished.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

input:

```
[{
  id: 1,
  name: foo
  modelChildren: [
   {
    id: 2,
    name: bar,
    modelChildren: [
      {
      id: 3,
      name: foobar
      },
      {
      id: 4,
      name: foobarfoo
      }
    ] 
   }
  ] 
}]
```

expected result:

```
[{
   id: 1,
   name: foo,
   level: 1
 {
   id: 2,
   name: bar,
   level: 2
 },
 {
   id: 3,
   name: foobar,
   level: 3
 },
 {
   id: 4,
   name: foobarfoo
   level: 3
 }]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be quite easy, it is just [Tree Traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal)

So you just need to traverse it and remember the level, while storing "nodes" when you are in them.

For example this code

```
const source = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'foo',
    modelChildren: [
        {
            id: 2,
            name: 'bar',
            modelChildren: [
                {
                    id: 3,
                    name: 'foobar'
                },
                {
                    id: 4,
                    name: 'foobarfoo'
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
}, {
    id: 5,
    name: 'foo',
    modelChildren: [
        {
            id: 6,
            name: 'bar',
            modelChildren: [
                {
                    id: 7,
                    name: 'foobar'
                },
                {
                    id: 8,
                    name: 'foobarfoo'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            id: 9,
            name: 'bar',
            modelChildren: [
                {
                    id: 10,
                    name: 'foobar'
                },
                {
                    id: 11,
                    name: 'foobarfoo'
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
}
];
const newSource = [];
const _ = require('lodash');

function doIt(items, level) {
    if (!items) {
        return;
    }

    items.forEach(item => {
        newSource.push(_.merge({level}, _.pick(item, ['id', 'name'])));
        doIt(item.modelChildren, level + 1);
    })
}

doIt(source, 1);
console.log(newSource);
```

Having this output

```
[ { level: 1, id: 1, name: 'foo' },
  { level: 2, id: 2, name: 'bar' },
  { level: 3, id: 3, name: 'foobar' },
  { level: 3, id: 4, name: 'foobarfoo' },
  { level: 1, id: 5, name: 'foo' },
  { level: 2, id: 6, name: 'bar' },
  { level: 3, id: 7, name: 'foobar' },
  { level: 3, id: 8, name: 'foobarfoo' },
  { level: 2, id: 9, name: 'bar' },
  { level: 3, id: 10, name: 'foobar' },
  { level: 3, id: 11, name: 'foobarfoo' } ]
```